# QDomDocument: setContent() return false

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have a problem while i try to use `setContent()` into a QDomDocument object..

Here is the code:

```
QFile f("database.xml");
if(!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
    cout << "Error: file not correctly opened." << endl;

QDomDocument doc("database");
QString errorStr;
int errorLine;
int errorColumn;
if(!doc.setContent(&f, false, &errorStr, &errorLine, &errorColumn)){
    cout << "Error: " << errorStr.toStdString() << " at line " << errorLine << " column " << errorColumn << endl;
}
f.close();
```

and it print:

`Error: unexpected end of file at line 1 column 1`

How can i solve this mistake?

Here is the contents of the file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myLibrary>
<movie>
    <price>5</price>
    <title>Star Wars 4</title>
    <register>George Lukas</register>
    <year>1977</year>
    <durate>192</durate>
</movie>
<movie>
    <price>8</price>
    <title>Rambo 1</title>
    <register>Joe Clarkson</register>
    <year>2012</year>
    <durate>167</durate>
</movie>
</myLibrary>
```

Comment: Do not use an empty file or have an valid xml header (just a guess). Could post the two first lines of the xml?

Comment: Try specifying an absolute path to your XML in the `QFile` constructor.

Comment: Wow, it works! But why does it work? how can i not specify the absolute path without giving me an error? @kefir500 Thanks!!

Comment: @Lubiz See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is an invalid path to your XML file.

If you are trying to open the file which is located in the same directory with your executable, use the [`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) method which return the needed path. Otherwise the process working directory will be used (which is not always an executable directory).

```
QFile f(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/database.xml");
```

I guess you did not notice the `Error: file not correctly opened.` warning, did you?

Comment: @Lubiz If this answer helped you, I would be grateful if you would upvote it and/or mark it as accepted.